# Create a list having 2 objects with number one in ascending and other in descending merged into one

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

Sort list based on the following :
One list is in ascending and the other is in descending order, which are then merged into one list with maintaining the order.

There are 2 lists A and B with numbers attached like following:

```
Eg: 
A1  B2
A2  B3
A6  B4
A7  B8
A10 B9
```

Sorted Oder will be:

```
A1
A2
B4
B3
B2
A6
A7
B9
B8
A10
```

Any suggestion will be helpful

**EDIT**
I have made the program in java using algorithm suggested by @karzler007

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        a.add(1);
        a.add(2);
        a.add(6);
        a.add(7);
        a.add(10);

        b.add(2);
        b.add(3);
        b.add(4);
        b.add(8);
        b.add(9);

        int i = a.size() - 1;
        int j = b.size() - 1;

        int k = a.size() + b.size() - 1;
        List<Integer> ans = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int h = 0; h < k + 1; h++) {
            ans.add(0);
        }

        while (k >= 0) {
            if (j < 0) {
                while (i >= 0) {
                    ans.set(k--, a.get(i--));
                }
            } else if (i < 0) {
                int l = 0;
                while (l <= j) {
                    ans.set(k--, b.get(l++));
                }
            } else {
                while (a.get(i) >= b.get(j)) {
                    ans.set(k--, a.get(i--));
                }
                int m = j;
                int n = j;
                while (j >= 0 && b.get(j) >= a.get(i)) {
                    j--;
                }
                m = j + 1;
                for (int e = m; e <= n; e++) {
                    ans.set(k--, b.get(e));
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(ans);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions for improving the code is welcome.

Comment: Is the given lists already sorted or you need to sort them first?

Comment: Are you sure A6 element is at the last position after merging?

Comment: Yes, as B2, B3, B4 is before 6(A6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A modified version of merge sort is what you are looking at. Instead of the two sorted arrays both in either non-decreasing or non-increasing fashion, you would now be considering one array to be in non-decreasing order and the other in non-increasing order.  The following code snippet performs the modified merging step.

```
// a is in non-decreasing order, b is in non-increasing order.

public static int[] merge(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int[] ans = new int[a.length + b.length];
    int i = a.length - 1, j = 0, k = ans.length;

    while (k > 0)
        ans[--k] = 
            (j > b.length-1 || (i >= 0 && a[i] >= b[j])) ? a[i--] : b[j++];
    return ans;
 }
```

**EDIT:** Apologies, I understood the question incorrectly. Please find below the corrected version of the algorithm.

```
    int a[] = {1, 2, 6, 7, 10};
    int b[] = {2, 3, 4, 8, 9};
    int[] ans = new int[a.length + b.length];
    int i = a.length - 1;
    int j = b.length - 1;
    int k = a.length + b.length - 1;
    while (k >= 0) {
        if (j < 0) {
            while (i >= 0) {
                ans[k--] = a[i--];
            }
        } else if (i < 0) {
            int l = 0;
            while (l <= j) {
                ans[k--] = b[l++];
            }
        } else {
            while (a[i] >= b[j]) {
                ans[k--] = a[i--];
            }
            int m = j;
            int n = j;
            while (j >= 0 && b[j] >= a[i]) {
                j--;
            }
            m = j + 1;
            for (int e = m; e <= n; e++) {
                ans[k--] = b[e];
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ans));
```

The above algorithm does provide you the desired output:

```
   [1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 6, 7, 9, 8, 10]
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I tried but the result coming is [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

Comment: Series A will be in ascending but if part of B comes in between then it will be in descending order.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. Your series A may look like {1,2,5,6,8}, while your B may be {10,7,4,3}. So, your answer then would be {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}? Or if you mean it different, can you provide (based on this use case), what is your expected output?

Comment: If A ={1,2,5,6,8}  B={10,7,4,3} then out put will be {1,2,4,3,5,6,7,8,10}. It means A will be in ascending and if part of B comes in between the series it will be descending. Here such range in B is only{3,4} so it is descending{4,3}

Comment: Okay, got it. Have provided a corrected version of the algo.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Its bit complex for me but output is correct.

Comment: The idea is to basically keep copying the elements of A into ans as long as a[i] > b[j] (note that I begin from the end of the lists). When you encounter b[j] > a[i], then simply store the indices m and n where the elements of b are greater than a[i]. Then run the loop from m to n as in the case of the algorithm to copy the elements from b into ans. The first two if statements take care of the situation when either of i or j becomes < 0.

Comment: I am trying to convert the same in Java using List collections.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Merge Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Top-down_implementation_using_lists) algorithm will help you. Look at `merge` stage.

As in the algorithm on `merge` stage you also have two sorted lists. So take from list A from start but from list B from end.

Answer (score 0):

If your list are made of String:

```
Collections.sort(listA);
Collections.sort(listB);
Collections.reverse(listB);
List<String> mergedList= new ArrayList<String>(listA);
mergedList.addAll(listB);
```

Comment: Answer will be then [A1, A2, A6, B4, B3, B2] but I am expecting different result.

Comment: The occurrence of B will be descending and A will be ascending, but they will be in order so its not necessary all As will be together and Bs together.